# Interpreting multiple regression - colonial data

Tags: r

**I've made three different multiple regressions and would love some help interpreting the results.**

*Model 1* is the effect of X =  High property Right Score on Y = (natural log of)GDP in constant price, with controls x2 = score 0-100 index measuring economic transformation during colonial occupation and x3 = score 0-100 index measuring political transformation during colonial occupation.

*Model 2:* Same as above but only for former French colonies

*Model 3:* Same as above but only for former British colonies

My current interpretation is as follows:

Model 1 my coefficient gives me:

```
exp(0.198) – 1)* 100 = 15,8%
```

increase in GDP with one indexpoint increase of Property Rights when both economic transformation and pol transformation is held constant.

[regression results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94mdN.png)

**My question are as follows:**

1. My effect seems quite large. The actual range of property rights is values from around 45 to 55, so the full range of possible
   values are not observed in the data since the countries have
   relatively average property rights cores. is this a problem?
2. Can I interpret the coefficients of my controls, econtrans and poltrans, substantively? other than, it seems that political
   transformation in the colonial era has some additive effects on gdp,
   that is not accounted for by the other predictors?
3. Should I add an interaction term instead such as `lm(y=ln_GDPpcconstant2010 ~ x=PropertyRightScore*UKorFrance_dummy + econtrans + poltrans, data = data)`. This is essentially what I've done in the plot below, but I'm quite confused as to if they are different from each other..

[image: interactionregression]
`

**All insights and help is greatly appreciated!**

Comment: Heres the image i've tried adding in the last question: https://pasteboard.co/K4sNm4L.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**
Low variability on your X means that you'll have less precision in your estimates, but that doesn't seem to be a problem as your coefficient's variations are already low. For more information, look into [this CrossValidated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161926/there-are-low-variations-in-the-explanatory-variables).

**2.**
It's very hard that you don't have an omitted variable that affects you Y, given the very complex nature of what determines GDP, and how hard is to condense all the political and economic characteristics into two indexes. As this indexes have a lot of things inside them, it's also hard to interpret them (the "effect of a gain of 1 on the idex of political transformation on the GDP" isn't much clear). Having said this, if you're not too much concerned with this fact, and you think that the indexes are well made, then they should capture the affects that the economics and politics characteristics have on the GDP. There can be other dimensions that you could want to look into, such as institutions.

**3.** From the plot, they wouldn't be different if one of the lines were contained in the other's confidence interval (grey area), which is not true. In the summary, you can see that both the coefficient associated with the interaction (slope of the lines) and with the dummy (intercept of the lines) are significantly different than 0.

Comment: thank you so much - it's very helpful! 
I agree, even though the indexes seem good and have many indicators I will avoid claiming about causality.. 

Regarding your answer to question 3, is my interaction slope the "propertyRightScore:kolonimagtUK" and can I interpret the result as I would a normal regression coefficient or is it a comparison with 0, in my case france? 

Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, that is the interaction coefficient i was talking about, and it's interpreted as the difference of the slopes of UK and France. If it's significantly different than 0, the slopes are different (so yes, the same interpretation in that sense). The difference with dummies that you might be thinking about is if you want to find the slope of UK: you need to sum the interaction coefficient with the France coefficient, that will actually be the "propertyRightScore" (as France is omitted). If this helps, please accept the answer so the question is marked as solved.

Comment: Awesome, I have marked it as solved! 

I've taken the natural log of my dependent var, so i'm used to calucalting my coefficients as follows:
exp(0.058) – 1)* 100 = 7,8%
which I now sum with:
exp(0.144) – 1)* 100 = 15,4%
= 23,2 %, 

So that one unit increase in the property right score is associated with an 23,2 % increase in my GDP var for former British colonies. As the plot show from my previous post, this shows that the effect of one unit increase of property rights are higher in the British colonies compared with the french. Do you buy that interpretation?

Comment: I'm not sure what does the (exp(beta)-1)*100 do, shouldn't you simply do 0.058+0.144=0.202, or a change in 1 of the property right score means a 20,2% change in gdp for british ex-colonies? I'm actually not sure...